# Error on Record<> datatype in typescript/angular

Tags: angular, typescript, types

I have this error `Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'Record<ExportableType, PayAccountingLine[][]>': leaves, lates, corrections` on a typescript variable `groupedAccountingLines` type and I can't understand why I'm getting it.

My code :

```
type ExportableType = 'leaves' | 'lates' | 'corrections';
groupedAccountingLines: Record<ExportableType, PayAccountingLine[][]>;
        
this.groupedAccountingLines = this.exportableTypes.reduce((acc, type) => {
    const data = groupBy(this.filterLines(changes['payAccountingLines'].currentValue, changes['payPeriod'].currentValue, type), (l) => `${l.owner.employeeNumber}_${l.source.externalAccountId}`);
    const groupAsArrayOfArray = Object.values(data).reduce((a, b) => [...a, b], [] as PayAccountingLine[][]);
    return {
        ...acc,
        [type]: groupAsArrayOfArray
    };
}, {});
```

The object returned by the reduce is an object that contains three key `'leaves' | 'lates' | 'corrections'` so why am I getting this error ?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

With the limited type information this snippet delivers, my guess would be that the error message stems from the intial value which is untyped. Probably something like this would be the solution:

```
type ExportableType = 'leaves' | 'lates' | 'corrections';
groupedAccountingLines: Record<ExportableType, PayAccountingLine[][]>;
        
this.groupedAccountingLines = this.exportableTypes.reduce((acc, type) => {
    const data = groupBy(this.filterLines(changes['payAccountingLines'].currentValue, changes['payPeriod'].currentValue, type), (l) => ${l.owner.employeeNumber}_${l.source.externalAccountId});
    const groupAsArrayOfArray = Object.values(data).reduce((a, b) => [...a, b], [] as PayAccountingLine[][]);
    return {
        ...acc,
        [type]: groupAsArrayOfArray
    };
}, {} as Record<ExportableType, PayAccountingLine[][]>);
```

Comment: This is correct.  You basically always need to use an `as` assertion when building an object through iteration since it's not complete when you start the iteration.